# Any good resource for solving power system optimization in GAMS?

Tags: reference-request, gams, energy

I am looking for some resources to learn the modelling tricks of GAMS in power system optimisation problems.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a good reference that has been published by Alireza Soroudi.

- [Power System Optimization Modeling in GAMS](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783319623498)

Comment: Thanks for sharing the source